# Extract / scrap data from PDF with python

Tags: python, html, pdf, web-scraping, extract

I am trying to find a solution to automate a task. In effect, I have a PDF file that I get from a website:

For example the following PDF: https://www.dgssi.gov.ma/sites/default/files/vulnerabilites_affectant_plusieurs_produits_de_cisco_13.pdf

I want to collect the information from the file in the form of a Python Dictionary {'bold sentence': 'the sentences after the bold sentence'}

Example: {....... , 'Solution': 'Veuillez se référer aux bulletins de sécurité de Cisco pour mettre à jours vos équipements', .....}

I already tried to transform the PDF to HTML and do some web scraping but there is no way to make the difference between several HTML tags because all the tags are similar.

If you can propose to me a solution or a code to make the extraction in the form of a dictionary I will be very grateful.

Any help would be appreciated, and if I need to be more specific let me know.

Comment: This will be difficult, as PDF is a format intended for displaying, not for analysis. There is no markup that would devide text into logical sections. PDFs merely store the positions of text glyphs, thus any further document analysis relies on heuristics that may or may not work, depending on the specific case.

Comment: That said, you may want to give [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) (and perhaps [camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)) a try, which implement PDF text extraction features.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT - adding another approach

Basically, P**DFs don't contain bold or italic text**. But, they do contain variants of the same font-family to get bold text. we can take advantage of this and search for the font-name for the text and see if it contains "bold".

You could use `extract_pages` and iterate over every character and check the font name to see if it contains "bold".

you could also use [`pdfplumber`](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) to achieve the same outcome

```
with pdfplumber.open(file_to_parse) as pdf: 
    text = pdf.pages[0]
    clean_text = text.filter(lambda obj: not (obj["object_type"] == "char" and "Bold" in obj["fontname"]))
    print(clean_text.extract_text())
```

---

I would convert the file to doc using methods described at the end, and that it would be much easier to parse, BUT I haven't done that in a long time.

##### Converting to DOC

***first option*** - using [`LibreOffice`](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/sbasic/python/main0000.html)

```
lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc '/your/file.pdf'
```

***second option*** - using only python

```
import os
import subprocess

for top, dirs, files in os.walk('/my/pdf/folder'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            abspath = os.path.join(top, filename)
            subprocess.call('lowriter --invisible --convert-to doc "{}"'
                            .format(abspath), shell=True)
```

then extract all bold sentences:

```
from docx import *

document = Document('path_to_your_files')
bolds=[]
italics=[]
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if run.italic :
            italics.append(run.text)
        if run.bold :
            bolds.append(run.text)

boltalic_Dict={'bold_phrases':bolds,
              'italic_phrases':italics}
```

Comment: Hi! Interesting approach! I haven't tested yet, but in general is it reliable? I mean, is it better than a regex approach?

Comment: you probably can, I'm editing my answer to add another approach and some explanations

Comment: How is the second option "using only Python" if it needs LibreOffice to be installed for `lowriter`?

Comment: Nice ideas! Remark: I agree with AKX that your statement "using only python" is a bit confusing because is depends on `lowriter` (it has to be installed!) and I have no idea what is that:)

Comment: Well, the new solution should be right up your alley